# Im creating a balistics calculator for a game I play in python. Its giving me an error

Tags: python

Okay so basically the code shown is only for calculating how far a bullet in the game goes to reach a certain damage value using linear interpolation. Now I recently changed it so the damage multiplier is multiplied by the range itself. However, it then started giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    R = M((u-L)*(b-a)/(u-v)+a)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Can ya'll find out what is causing this and how I should fix it? Here is the code

```
#u = max dmg
#v = min dmg
#a = max dmg range
#b = min dmg range
#L = specific damage
#R = specific range
#M = damage multiplier
#ROC is (v-u)(b-a)
#(R-a)(v-u)/(b-a) + u = L is function for damage at specific range
#(u-L)(b-a)/(u-v) + a = R is for finding range at specific damage

u = float(input("Max Damage: "))
v = float(input("Min Damage: "))
a = float(input("Max Damage Distance (The LOWER Stud Value): "))
b = float(input("Min Damage Distance (The HIGHER Stud Value): "))
L = float(input("Damage: "))
M = float(input("Damage Multiplier: "))
R = M((u-L)*(b-a)/(u-v)+a)

if R < a:
  L = M*u
elif R > b:
  L = M*v

print(L, "Damage at", R, "Studs")
```

Comment: What you want to achieve by this code `R = M((u-L)*(b-a)/(u-v)+a)` ?

Comment: You need a `*` symbol for multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Error hints that you are trying to call a float value. Indeed, expression `M ( (u-L)*(b-a)/(u-v)+a )` implies call of M with argument `(u-L)*(b-a)/(u-v)+a`. I would guess that you meant to multiply M by this value. In that case, you should type `R = M * ( (u-L)*(b-a)/(u-v)+a )`

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis right after M in `M((u-L)*(b-a)/(u-v)+a)` it interpreted as calling something on M, which is a primitive data type. Replacing it with `M*((u-L)*(b-a)/(u-v)+a)` should fix all of your problems.